# Is it appropriate to use two consecutive "-ing" clause?

Tags: writing-style

> The Cheng-guang (law-enforcement staff) are semi-barbaric, stirring up
>   a universal hatred for the government, thus endangering the stability
>   of the whole political system.

In this sentence I've devised, I have used two "-ing" structures as clauses describing activities / consequences. Is it appropriate to use two consecutive -ing clauses? Maybe I should create another sentence in which I replace the second -ing clause?

Comment: There is no limit. You could add another twenty. Or five hundred. Or really *any* number at all.

Comment: You might want to make it easier on the reader though - perhaps an 'and' before the 'thus'. Incidentally, this is not the usual stacked -ing clauses (all equally referencing the subject) usage: 'He sat there watching the geese along the towpath, smiling at the passers-by and hailing the occasional boatsman.' Your second -ing clause is semantically dependent on the first (hence the 'thus'). Deleting the first would leave nonsense (deleting any in my example would leave a meaningful residue). You've come up with a special case!

Comment: Why do you think the gerunds might disagree with each other? Is there some reason you are particularly unhappy with the structure or do you suspect that English grammar frowns upon multiple gerunds in a sentence? Can you expand?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's writing advice. Grammar or usage has no objection to the OP's sentence.

Comment: As Edwin Ashworth perceptively noticed, I have come up with a special case. This is delibrately made up. Sorry that I neglect to clarify my doubt. I was wondering whether it is inappropriate to put two causal relations into one sentence, whether it will be better to divide it into two sentences.

Comment: No, it's fine. You need the connector, though - 'thus', 'and thus', 'and so', 'thereby'...

Answer (score 2):

As RegDwighт notes in the comments:

> There is no limit. You could add another twenty. Or five hundred. Or really any number at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is appropriate. But doesn't the usage in question deemphasize everything that comes after the first comma, as if it were parenthesized?